# is it possible to get rid of my entire rubies installations in one shot without rvm?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

if not pls explain how ? i have a version of ruby but rvm refuses to acknowledge that. so i want to uninstall it without using rvm. how ? i wish to see "nothing" on typing $ which ruby.
i am working on ubuntu

Comment: Did you istall it from your package manager (`apt`) or from source?

Comment: i tried compilng myself .. but gave errors. then i used 'apt' and finally rvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could always **rm -Rf ~/.rvm**.  That's where all your RVM-installed rubies live.  And in addition to that, remove any lines you added to your **.bashrc** while installing RVM.

Removing the Ruby installed on the system by Ubuntu is different, you'll need to **sudo apt-get remove ruby1.8** or similar.  This may or may not uninstall your Rubygems, I'm not sure.  And be aware that you're just going to have to reinstall that, since RVM needs Ruby to run.

Once you're back to a stock Ubuntu setup (as far as Ruby is concerned), try reading my directions on how to [install RVM on Linux](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/installrvmlinux.htm).

Comment: If Ubuntu is anything like its progenitor, Debian, then ruby is in /usr/lib/ruby/<ruby-version>, with gems stored separately in /var/lib/gems/<ruby-version>.